# Why the direction of a cross product vector multiplication is considered perpendicular to the area?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I know why cross product is used and how to use it. I also understand that, for doing math we need to consider a direction for the result we have got by doing cross product vector multiplication.

But actually why is this direction considered perpendicular to the area? Is there any specific reason or is this just a traditional way?

Comment: Because in three dimensions $u \times v \cong \star (u \wedge v)$ and $\mathbb R^n$ can be canonically identified with its cotangent bundle and $\star (dx \wedge dy) = dz$ and basis (co)vectors are orthogonal by construction.

Comment: Thanks Brevan. But some explanation would be better for understanding.

Comment: The comment I left is probably only useful much later in one's mathematical journey than their first introductions to the cross product, but the basic idea is that the wedge product $u \wedge v$ can be geometrically identified with the parallelogram spanned by $u$ and $v$. The cross product turns out to be the thing dual to this parallelogram, and since it's 3D space and a parallelogram has two dimensions, the dual has one dimension so is a vector (hence the cross product is a vector, and not a bivector). Duality also implies it must be orthogonal.

Comment: Checking now, Wikipedia has a good image of this on its page on the Cross Product, under the "external product" section (and then further explanation in its "Generalization" section)

Answer (score 0):

This is as the case because the standard/euclidean scalar product $<-,->$ of the cross-product $v \times u$ with the vectors v and u is zero and therefor, by linearity, zero for all vectors in the plane that is generated by v and u.
And perpendicularity, or rather orthogonality, in respect to a scalar product, is defined by the scalar product being zero.

If you are now wondering why the cross-product points in one of two direction, this depends on the order of your cross product as $u \times v = - v \times u$, this is the convention, maybe because this is compatible with the mathematical direction, counter clockwise, if you go through $u,v,u \times v$.